# Is there a $\sigma$-algebra which has countably many elements but not finitely many?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I couldn't think anything about this question from a book by Bass:

> Does there exist a $σ$-algebra which has countably many elements, but not finitely many?

May I get a hint please?
Thanks!

Comment: If it contains a countably infinite family of nonempty pairwise disjoint sets, you know that is contains at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ elements.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320035/if-s-is-an-infinite-sigma-algebra-on-x-then-s-is-not-countable)