# Countable $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let  $\Sigma$ be a countable $\sigma$-algebra.

Show that there is a sequence $A_1,A_2,...$ of disjoint elements of $\Sigma$ such that every $B$ in $\Sigma$ is a countable union of elements in $\{A_n\}$.

My attempt:

Since $\Sigma$ is countable, we have $\Sigma = \{B_1,B_2,B_3,...\}$

Then I took:

$A_1 = B_1$

$A_2 = B_2 - B_1$

$A_3 = B_3 - (B_2 \cup B_1) $

$A_n = B_n - \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}{B_i} $

The sequence $\{A_n\}$ is disjoint and $\{A_n\}\subset \Sigma$.

I'm having trouble  showing that every $B$ in $\Sigma$ is a countable
union of $\{A_n\}$.

How do I show that every $B$ in $\Sigma$ is a countable
union of $\{A_n\}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such thing as a countable $\sigma$-algebra: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320035/if-s-is-an-infinite-sigma-algebra-on-x-then-s-is-not-countable

Comment: There's such a thing as an at most countable $\sigma$-algebra!  Well, we know that it has to be finite.  So I suppose that it would be more accurate to say that there exists a finite $\sigma$-algebra...  Is this question moot then?  Nothing useful to glean?

Comment: Byron Schmuland is right:  there is no such thing as a countable σ-algebra (in the sense of infinity countable $\sigma$-algebra).  Then, either the question above is void or we must read it as "Let $\Sigma$ be an at most countable $\sigma$-algebra", and then the question becomes actually about finite $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: Well, I think there is a mistake in my homework.  Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Santos countably-generated $\sigma-$algebra?

Comment: @ClarkZinzow same question

Comment: @Ramiro same question