# Measure theory; proving an infinite partition exists from a sigma-algebra.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, set-partition

I'm really new to measure theory and have trouble with interpreting a question.

We have a space $A$ with $\mathbb{A}$ a $\sigma$-algebra with infinitely many elements. Now I need to show an infinite partition exists.

Of course we first need to define what an infinite partition is. It is a countable infinite sequence of non-empty and disjoint sets which union is $A.$

So we know there are infinite elements in the $\sigma$-algebra. I would argue we need to rearrange the elements of $\mathbb{A}$ to make them countable and then introduce a 'left-overs' subset that contains all elements that are outside of our countable division. I know this is probably very wrong but I would appreciate any steering in the right direction...

Comment: Are you sure you don't want each $A_j$ to be measurable? Otherwise, $\mathbb{A}$ being infinite implies $A$ is infinite. Hence, there exists a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of distinct elements of $A$. Then $A=(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{a_n\})\cup (A\setminus (\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{a_n\})),$ the union has infinitely many "summands" and each of these sets is clearly disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct.

If the space is finite then the sigma algebra if finite and your partition problem is easy enough.

If the sigma algebra  is infinite then it is uncountable.

Let $\Bbb{A}=\{A_i:i \in I\}$

Then you can take a countable sequence $\{A_n:n\in \Bbb{N}\} \subset \Bbb{A}$

Now define $B_n=A_n \setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}A_k$ and $B_1=A_1$

Note that these sets are disjoint and belong to $\Bbb{A}$(since $\Bbb{A}$ is closed under set differences and unions)

Finally take $\Bbb{A}_n:=\{B_n\}$ and $\Bbb{A}_0=\Bbb{A} \setminus \{B_n: n \in \Bbb{N}\}$

So you  have a partition $\{ \Bbb{A}_n:n=0,1,2...\}$ of the sigma algebra.

Comment: **Example:** $A = [0,1]$, $\Bbb A$ the Borel subsets of $[0,1]$,  and $A_n=[0,1/n]$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$. In this case  $B_1=[0,1]$, $B_k = \emptyset$ for $k=2,3,\ldots$. Your procedure does not produce a  partition (of $A$, into $\Bbb A$-measurable sets, which is the (implicit)  goal).

Comment: @JohnDawkins the qeustion in the post is not clear and i though that the O.P wanted a partition of the sigma algebra

Comment: First of all thanks for your answers, it helps clarify things for me greatly. I don't see how, if the space is countably infinite, the sigma algebra would be uncountable. Also, I tried the following:

Let $C := \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{A}_{i}$. Then if $C$ is not already pairwise disjoint, we let $D=C_{i} \setminus ( B_{i}^{c} \cup B_{j}^{c})$. Then $B_{i} \setminus D = B_{i}^{c} \cup B_{j}$, which is an elements of $\mathbb{A}$. Same applies for $B_{j}$, therefore we have now divided our set into smaller sets of pairwise disjoint sets. Do this for all sets done. Correct?

Comment: @Mathbeginner take a look at this for a proof of the uncountability of the sigma algebra https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320035/if-s-is-an-infinite-sigma-algebra-on-x-then-s-is-not-countable#targetText=An%20immediate%20consequence%20is%20that%20the%20%CF%83%2Dalgebra%20is%20uncountable.&targetText=all%20lie%20in%20S%2C%20because,that%20they%20are%20pairwise%20disjoint.&targetText=So%20you%20get%20an%20injection,N%20is%20an%20uncountable%20set.

Comment: @Mathbeginner...i meant that if the sigma algebra is infinite the it is uncountable...not the space..my bad.

Comment: @MariosGretsas in your first answer, how do you construct that initially countable sequence $\{ A_{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} \subset \mathbb{A}$? 
I don't really understand your $\mathbb{A} = \{ A_{i} : i \in I \}$...

Comment: @Mathbeginner the set $\{A_i:i \in I\}$  is the whole sigma algebra which is uncountable (if we assume tha has finite elements) form this family then i chose a countable sequence of sets $A_n$

Comment: If the sigma algebra has uncountable elements and in general is infinite ,then i can create a family of distinct countable sets by axiom of choise for example

Comment: But you let $\mathbb{A} = \{ A_{i} : i \in I \}$, then I would say each $A_{i}$ contains exactly one element from $A$, namely $a_{i}$, correct? But then all intersections are empty by your definition of $A_{i}$ and therefore we wouldn't need anything else... Where do I go wrong?

Comment: How do you know that singleton belong to $\Bbb{A}$?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{A}$ has infinite elements?

Comment: So what...? it note need to have singletons for having infinite elements.

Comment: That does not guarantee that has infinitely many singletons...If it has then your idea is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using @bof's argument from a related question:

Let $\mathcal B$ be an infinite $\sigma$-algebra on a set $\Omega$. Partition $\Omega$ into two disjoint nonempty sets $A_1,B_1\in\mathcal B$. At least one of $\mathcal B\cap\mathcal P(A_1)$ and $\mathcal B\cap\mathcal P(B_1)$ is infinite; otherwise, if $|\mathcal B\cap\mathcal P(A_1)|=m\lt\aleph_0$ and $|\mathcal B\cap\mathcal P(B_1)|=n\lt\aleph_0$, we would have $|\mathcal B|=mn\lt\aleph_0$. We may assume that $\mathcal B\cap\mathcal P(B_1)$ is infinite. Next, partition $B_1$ into two disjoint nonempty sets $A_2,B_2\in\mathcal B$ so that $\mathcal B\cap\mathcal P(B_2)$ is infinite. Continuing in this way, we get an infinite sequence $A_1,A_2,A_3,\dots$ of pairwise disjoint nonempty elements of $\mathcal B$. (Every infinite Boolean algebra contains such a sequence; we haven't used the $\sigma$ yet.) Since $\mathcal B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, the union of each subsequence belongs to $\mathcal B$, showing that $|\mathcal B|\ge2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: I am not familiar with your $\aleph_{0}$ symbol. What do you mean with this?

Comment: @Mathbeginner read $|A|< \aleph_0$ as $A$ is finite and $|A|=\aleph_0$ as $A$ is countably infinite, if you prefer. $\aleph_0$ is the cardinal number corresponding to $\Bbb N$, the smallest infinity. I'm a set-theoretical topologist by training...

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.