# Papa Rudin abstract integration exercise $1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, measurable-sets

**There is the exercise:**

**Does there exist an infinite $\sigma$-algebra which has only countably many members?**

Intuitively I think that the answer is no but I've really trouble to proof it.

[image]
**This is one proof But I have few questions about it.
I don't understand this part in this proof: " If not, then every other measurable set of $X$ must intersect both $E$ and $E^c$ nontrivially."**

I also don't understand why is $F_n$ a set of size $n$ measurable sets? for example $F_2$ has three members . by this logic $F_n$ should have $n+1$ members.
why do we need to make $n$ sufficiently large?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $S$ is an infinite $\sigma$ algebra on $X$ then $S$ is not countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320035/if-s-is-an-infinite-sigma-algebra-on-x-then-s-is-not-countable)

Comment: @AnneBauval no this one doesn't answer

Comment: Though the title is exactly what you want and the answers are numerous and rich.

Comment: And why don’t you understand it? We can’t help if we don’t know what the specific problem is

Comment: @FShrike I will edit it

Comment: @FShrike done it's edited

Answer (score 0):

- Answer to your main question: "every other measurable set of $X$ must intersect both $E$ and $E^c$ nontrivially" must be understood as: "every *nonempty* $E'\in\mathfrak M$ distinct from $E$ and $E^c$ must satisfy $E'\cap E\ne \varnothing$ and $E'\cap E^c\ne\varnothing$" i.e. "[...] must satisfy $A\not\subset E^c$ and $A\not\subset E$".
  Since $\varnothing\ne E\ne X$, this is the exact negation of "$E$ or $E^c$ contains a *nonempty* measurable $E'$ properly contained in it", i.e. of "there exists a nonempty $E'\in\mathfrak M$ such that $E'\subsetneq E$ or $E'\subsetneq E^c$".
- I agree with you that $F_n$ is of size $n+1$ rather than $n$. It is just a blunder, I guess.
- **But** the rest of this solution seems to me nonsense hence I wouldn't trust [the file where you found it](https://iseulbee.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/RCA-Solution.pdf): the "set $F$ of measurables sets $E$ such that $E$ appears in all $F_n$ for sufficiently large $n$" is unquestionably "well defined" but may be empty and anyway, the remaining sentences have neither head nor tail to me.

Now, may [If $S$ is an infinite $\sigma$ algebra on $X$ then $S$ is not countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320035/if-s-is-an-infinite-sigma-algebra-on-x-then-s-is-not-countable) help?